# candid candor, splendid splendor, squalid squalor, rigid rigor -- finding examples

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, reference

The etymological fallacy is exposed by examples as humid/humor, liquid/liquor, and, I think, some others.

This pattern, at least as applied to the examples in the subject line, is familiar to speakers of English, but not productive.  There are lots of patterns in the English language of which that can be said.

My question is: What sorts of reference works or web sites or whatever, enables one to find such phenomena and somewhat comprehensive lists of instances?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is, could you clarify? The term [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy) is used more commonly to refer to erroneously conflating the original meaning of a word with its modern meaning. It appears, instead, that you're referring to the phenomenon of words which appear similar, but aren't related to each other etymologically?

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.facebook.com/dictionarycom/posts/10151824949684874) uses the term 'divergent etymology' to apply to the way a word's meanings have split. Any work on etymology will be bound to show certain examples. Or are you just concerned about this morphological connection?

Comment: My question is about _patterns_ followed by a number of words that may be small but nonetheless large enough to make the pattern a pattern.  Another example involves forming nouns from verbs by adding "-al", as in trial or removal (probably around 50 verbs do this); another forms nouns from verbs by adding a final "-t"$ as in complaint, restraint;  there are others.  I'm wondering if someone has collected and organized them.

Comment: Ah. Well, in many languages, these patterns are far stricter rules about how to conjugate base words into their various forms. English is derivative of a few dozen languages, and as such carries many such vestigial patterns, with many more exceptions than adherences. If you do find such a collection, I'm sure it would be pretty fascinating to read, so be sure to share the link.

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of "derivational morphology"? That seems to be what your examples represent, for the most part. In general, the question seems to be about morphemes and how to find lists of words where they are used. I don't know if there is an established collection of these for English, but they've definitely been studied by linguists.

Comment: @webbcode : "English is derivative of a few dozen languages, and as such carries many such vestigial patterns"  So my question is whether anyone has comprehensively tabulated these in a reference work?

Answer (score 3):

Latin may give access.
Can you upload a Latin Dictionary with a search facility for '*****idus'?

I've dredged up these examples without this facility: (Smith's Shorter on line)

> **tepor**, warmth, tepidus; **torpor**, torpidus; **foetor**, stench, foetidus;

Many of your lost etymologies may have split off in classical, or in late Latin. for example:

> **valor**, validus;  (though you can see the connection)
>   **horror**, what makes you bristle,  horridus, bristling;
>   **vapor**: > vapidus I. that has emitted steam or vapor, i. e. that has lost its life and spirit, spoiled, flat, vapid. (Lewis and Short
>   via **www.perseus.tufts**)

Oxfam bookstore produced *New Junior Latin Course*, Thompson and Penn 1965. with a page of similar groups, p.327.
[image: Thompson & Penn p.327]

Answer (score 3):

Such triple series are typical of special Latin verbs that we have to translate with to be + adjective such as cande:re to be bright white. They have an adjective ending in -idus and a noun ending in -or. I guess that there are about 30 of such verbs. What exactly do you mean by etymological fallacy? That in English the noun has developed new meanings? I would say that is normal and no fallacy. Already in Latin the adjectives and nouns can diverge according to semantic lines.

Comment: The etymological fallacy is that a word's meaning is necessarily what its etymology suggests it should be.

Answer (score 2):

***"Web sites or whatever,"*** (supplementary to previous post...***"finding examples"***)

> http://www.affixes.org/o/-or2.html yields:
>   -or affix:  horror, pallor, stupor, tremor, fervor, valor,
>   -id affix: acrid, morbid, putrid, (stupid) and torrid

And right on subject:
   **Lucie Pultrova**, 2007 
***[The Latin Adjectives with the Suffix -idus](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/113997/N_GraecoLatina_12-2007-1_7.pdf?sequence=1)***.

> "All in all, I believe that we must start from the fact that neither
>   in the case of the verbs of the type calēre, nor in the case of the
>   adjectives in -idus we deal with deverbative derivations; they do not
>   express the relation towards an action, but they denote the quality of
>   a substance. From the semantic aspect then we must regard the
>   adjectives in -idus  as “adjectives of quality”. The same applies also
>   to the related abstract nouns in -or (calor) – also these are clear
>   cut qualitative abstract nouns, not verbal abstract nouns (nouns of
>   action)."

Although her examples are Latin, most of their English derivatives are well-known. And she outlines other explanations for the pattern, *vid. sup.* @rogermue.

Many of the etymons have already diverged, *-or <> -id*, in classical or medieval Latin.

Comment: The linked page is interesting, but it makes no attempt at comprehensiveness.

Comment: @MichaelHardy true **!** Is it a PhD for someone? The bibliography is brief.